# Why can't I parse the html result returned by my MVC partial view?

Tags: jquery, html, razor, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I get that the purpose of returning MVC partial views as html was meant to just magically load everything in the viewmodel being passed into my razor-templated view.

However, I only want to selectively load that html model data into my view from my ajax call. I have found zero documentation on parsing this stuff, with the exception being a snippet which supposedly parses the unformatted html into something queryable using jquery:

```
 var modelHTML = $.parseHTML(viewModelData);
```

I want to go a step further and do:

```
 var elements = $('<div></div>');
 elements.html(modelHTML);
 var matchingOption = $(elements).find("#selectListID option:first");
 alert(matchingOption.val);
```

but this returns a bunch of jibberish. Is there any way to parse the html returned from a partial view result carrying a viewmodel, rather than returning a json result?

Here's the gist of my controller code:

```
  public ActionResult _MyPartialView(_PartialViewModel pvm)
    {
         _PartialViewModel _pvm = pvm;

         _pvm.shapesList = new List<SelectListItem>();

          foreach(var item in context.shapesEntity.Where(x => x.shapeName.HasValue))
          {
               _pvm.ShapesList.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = item.id, Text = item.name});
          }

          return PartialView("_myPartialView", _pvm);
     }
```

*Note:: I have successfully replaced the HTML in my partial view with the html in this div. So that works and is the way I am seeing people use partial view html results. But I want to query this with jquery and use pieces of the result as I please.*

Comment: Could you show your controller code?

Comment: now that I have more debugging tools and have the answer to my syntax error, I'd like to note that $.parseHTML() was actually unnecessary. Jquery can query the viewmodel html data all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, I think I see where the problem is.

First of all on this line.

```
var modelHTML = $.parseHTML(viewModelData);
```

You don't need to use parseHTML (I doubt it'd hurt), because the return value of your action is already the HTML and you can just use that when setting the HTML of your div.

```
var elements = $('<div></div>');
elements.html(modelHTML);
var matchingOption = $(elements).find("#selectListID option:first");
```

All of that above looks fine, should do exactly what you want (assuming the HTML in your action has an ID called selectListID and it has an option in it).

I think the below line is where you have a mistake.

```
alert(matchingOption.val);
```

val is a function, so you're getting the function definition returned. What you want is something like this.

```
console.log(matchingOption.val());
```

You could of course use alert instead, I prefer console.log, you could also use `console.log(matchingOption)` to just spit out the object to your console.

Comment: Well, I feel silly. I now have console.log as a new resource (i'm in my first week of jquery and this an amazing tool I now have!). Also, really embarrassed to say...But I did realize the error was in my server query :/ I did switch .val to .val() and was able to catch my error with the help of your console.log suggestion which helped make my alert/log much more readable. Thanks so much. Also, thanks for explaining that I was seeing the function definition. I didn't realize that's what the "jibberish" was.